# Putting variables and links into data array Kendo Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have a dropdown I'm trying to turn into an Angular Kendo dropdown. In that translation I'm having a hard time trying to transition the links and the variables into the data array to populate it. Is there a trick to this? All I could find from google was strings.

The HTML variables and links

```
{{ user.name }}
/user
```

and the data array

```
public data: Array<any> = [{
      text: user.name,
      link: '/user'
  }];
```

I have tried escaping the quotes, with the quotes and without. I have also tried digging into the values within the user object like this.user.name. But it just all comes back with errors

Comment: Can you provide more details. The code snippets you tried, so that we can have more idea.

Comment: Hello @zazvorniki, could you be more explicit about your issue please?

Comment: put your html code for the drop down for more help

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar below.

```html
public data: Array<any> = [{
      text: `${user.name}`,
      link: '/user'
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer is right, but please comment if you need a specific answer.

From the documentation, this is the template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
      <p>T-shirt size:</p>
        <kendo-dropdownlist
            [data]="data"
            [textField]="'text'"
            [valueField]="'link'"
        >
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
    </div>
  `
})
class AppComponent {
    public listItems: Array<{ text: string, link: text }> = [
        { link: "/some/url/1", text: "name1" },
        { link: "/some/url/2", text: "name2" },
        { link: "/some/url/3", text: "name3" }
    ];
}
```

I hope you are passing the right information:
1. variable name : in your case data variable is `data` itself.
2. exact field names; in your case, `textField` is `text` and `valueField` is `link`

I hope this is what you are looking for. I am just guessing based on your question as you haven't provided a detailed code.

I hope this helps.

**Note: Please note that I have modified the above code (HTML template and Variable) as per your code in the question.**

Comment: @zazvorniki did this answer your question?